# React-native can not map tcp port with device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie in React-native. In the first project. I init react project with command line `react-native init <project name>` 
This environment:
nodejs: v4.5.0, npm: 4.1.2 and ANDROID_HOME. 
When I run `adb device`
[image]

But when I run project `react-native run-android`
[image]

I try run command line `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` but it not working.
Who can tell me fix this error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `Android SDK v23` should resolve your problem.

[image]

Update answer:

> Android API 23 I installed but when I install Android SDK Build-tool
>   23.0.1 it's working while Android SDK Build-tool 23.0.2 or 23.0.3 not working

Because `23.0.1` [is the default SDK version for a React Native project](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html#configure-your-sdk). I don't know how to modify this but if you want to see the build version, checkout this file `android/app/build.gradle`. You would see a section with following content:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Comment: It's amazing :)). Android API 23 I installed but when I install ```Android SDK Build-tool 23.0.1``` it's working while ```Android SDK Build-tool 23.0.2 or 23.0.3``` not working @@

Comment: Yep. Thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable developer options on your phone? if not check this line: [enable developer options on android device](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/)

Comment: Yes, my device is enable debug :). If disable debug, you run ```adb devices``` it will return null list :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Android build tools via Android Studio.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager
3. Click "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" at the bottom of the window
4. Find the referenced package and check it (see below)
5. Click "Install packages..."
6. Agree to the licences

[image: Android SDK Manager]

You should then be able to build onto the device.

Comment: This is my android SDK [link](http://s.pictub.club/2017/01/20/szgKPo.png)